# Why are '< and '> not being set within this vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a vimscript that turns a C++ declaration such as:

```
virtual int funct(int aaa=one, float b=two);
```

Into a definition:

```
int SomeClass::funct(int aaa, float b) {
}
```

.. that I would then add code to.  I want it to work with motions and visual mode selections, and so I grabbed the if statement from the vim help, and put my stuff afterwards.

```
nmap <silent> <F4> :set opfunc=TestMe<CR>g@
vmap <silent> <F4> :<C-U>call TestMe(visualmode(), 1)<CR>

function! TestMe(type, ...)
  " I grabbed the below from the help, but removed 
  " the 'y' at the end of each exe commands.

  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use gv command.
    silent exe "normal! gv"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]"
  endif

  " My code below:

  " gets rid of virtual keyword
  exec "'<,'>s/\\(\\s*\\)virtual\\s\\+/\\1/ge" 

  " gets rid of optional parameter assignments
  exec "'<,'>s/\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z_0-9\:]\\+//ge" 

  " adds <contents of A register>:: in front of function name
  exec "'<,'>g/\\s*[^\\s]*\\s*(.*)\\s*;\\s*$/norm! ==%%b\"aPa::" 

  " replaces ; with {} and newlines
  exec "'<,'>s/\\s*;\\s*$/ {\r\t}\r/g" 

  " The following is from vim help again:
  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

Here is the code I'm trying to test it on:

```
        int funct1();
        virtual int funct2(int a, float b);
        virtual int funct3(int aaa=one, float b=two);
        virtual Blah::Type funct3(int aaa=one, Another::Type b=two);
        Blah::Type funct3(int aaa=one, Another::Type b=two) = 0;
```

What I thought would happen is that the if statement would use the proper v command to select the pertinent text and then run my exec commands.  Those exec statements would then use '<,'>, to limit those commands to the selected section.  However, the first time I execute it will say "'< Mark not set." or something.  After that point, it seems to act on random lines (probably based on a previous visual selection).

Yet, when I manually visually select the code and execute each line manually on the : prompt, then it behaves just I'd expect.  What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably don't need the `c++` tag, this is really a pure `vim` question.

Comment: Though I thought I added both the vim and vimscript tag, I only see a vim tag.  I'm not sure where I went wrong, or how to fix it.

Comment: Note: This is a complex subject and there is a lot to do: - extract the current class name (which could be embedded in other classes and namespaces); - get rid of possible comments; - work even with multilines declarations; - remove some specifiers (`virtual`, `override`, `static`...); - keep some other (exception specifications, `const`...); - and so on. I have over 700 lines of vim script code + a few more hundred for decoding C++ constructs (See [lh-cpp-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/) `:GOTOIMPL` feature)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `range` after your function. For instance:

```
function! TestMe(type, ...) range
```

then use `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`.

See `:h function-range-example`.